# How to properly use PayloadAction with meta type in redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Simplified example

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    type Cake = {
      flavor: string;
      size: 'S' | 'M' | 'L';
    };

const initialState: { all: Cake[]; meta: { currentPage: number } } = {
  all: [],
  meta: {
    currentPage: 0,
  },
};

const cakeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cake',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchAll(
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<Cake[], string, { currentPage: number }>,
    ) {
      state.all = action.payload;
      state.meta = action.meta;
    },
  },
});

export default cakeSlice;
```

I am getting these errors.

```
Type '
(state: {
    all: {
        flavor: string;size: "S" | "M" | "L";
    } [];meta: {
        currentPage: number;
    };
}, action: PayloadAction < Cake[], string, {
    currentPage: number;
}, never > ) => void ' is not assignable to type '
CaseReducer < {
    all: Cake[];meta: {
        currentPage: number;
    };
}, {
    payload: any;type: string;
} > | CaseReducerWithPrepare < {
    all: Cake[];meta: {
        currentPage: number;
    };
}, {
    payload: any;type: string;
} > '
```

```
Type '
(state: {
    all: {
        flavor: string;size: "S" | "M" | "L";
    } [];meta: {
        currentPage: number;
    };
}, action: PayloadAction < Cake[], string, {
    currentPage: number;
}, never > ) => void '
is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<{ all: Cake[]; meta: { currentPage: number; }; }, { payload: any; type: string; }>'.
Types of parameters 'action'
and 'action'
are incompatible.
Type '{ payload: any; type: string; }'
is not assignable to type 'PayloadAction<Cake[], string, { currentPage: number; }, never>'.
Property 'meta'
is missing in type '{ payload: any; type: string; }'
but required in type '{ meta: { currentPage: number; }; }
'.
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this? Was there an update to RTK that went out to solve the issue?

Comment: I think the latest version already solves this issue @ksav

Comment: I had the same question for a `PayloadAction<,,,Error>` and found this. Exactly the same problem and solution. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default behaviour of RTK is to create an action creator with only one argument and only a payload property. This behaviour cannot be modified by TS annotations, because TS annotations have no effect on runtime behaviour.

You can use [the `prepare` notation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#customizing-generated-action-creators) to define a function that overrides this default behaviour.
This function has the same signature & behaviour as the [`prepare` argument for createAction](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#using-prepare-callbacks-to-customize-action-contents), so you can find most of the relevant documentation there.

In your specific case, you'd want something along the lines of

```
const cakeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cake',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchAll: {
      reducer(
        state,
        action: PayloadAction<Cake[], string, { currentPage: number }>
      ) {
        state.all = action.payload
        state.meta = action.meta
      },
      prepare(payload: Cake[], currentPage: number) {
        return { payload, meta: { currentPage } }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here it is as a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwMZQKYEMaoMoBthKoA0cACugJ64ToAmAgkjMBAHYC+cAZlBCHAHIAAmloBXAB4ArAM4B6GBAi4A1sBgCA3AChtwVlihd0hOAGF0K1Im1w4rdCFQAuODJhR9Acx3tdSNnc4fXVgdFxsGExrAF4bO3DcVwBtAF04dBlzS1Q0ols4JyjXZDEoNANyLxc4AGY-P20A1iCkHLwCWLgUDCwOwgAKBAKHJ1cBNqsBfLsQ5nDI6Jm4UTFCKBkSgrsuVBgkAAt6XCT4u3PV9YHt87t3JZvbk2Y2V3IqGgYmFlYAHgsrHk3B5vCQEN0yhUYFUaqwxCAAEaoKBwdgAPkecAAlGdbncolgAHSJOBxZ4-QlgSjUOiY-HRQlFdCkjLfNiMvboTHsZa3MBoKloAZUj50VwA3KpEhISGoSroaquOGI5E44Z4i57MqsRBwEU02gkJklCHlOXQhXWTh+DU2852hpY-yBZSoQnULwDSY4fCEYlslqE3b7I4nAZA2pYjlRQkys3y6pYoA)

Comment: Thank you. I followed your advice but unfortunately, I'm still having the same issue. 



`
Property 'meta' is missing in type '{ payload: any; type: string; }' but required in type '{ meta: { currentPage: number; }; }'
`

Comment: Works nicely in this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-platform-w274k and also in the TS playground (edited that into the answer)

Which version of TS are you using?

Comment: I'm using typescript 3.7.5 sir

Comment: Very weird. I mean, it definitely works as seen in the playground & codesandbox. 
Any unusual `tsconfig` settings? Something like strictNullChecks disabled or something similar?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Here's my tsconfig.json https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/376#issuecomment-589641209

Comment: This is a huge pain point when using RTK & typescript.

Comment: @ksav what exactly? this question is about multiple different things in the end.

Comment: is there some global prepare method? Do i have to split all of the reducers into `reducer` and `prepare` ?

Comment: @pailhead in 98% of cases you should not have any need to use `prepare` at all - this is a very edge case use thing. So no, we don't expect people to use it often and certainly not on a global level.

Comment: I basically need something like this `export type ModuleAction<T = void> = PayloadAction<T> & {  meta?: { modulePath: ModulePath }}` Im working with a ton of different views in a react-mosaic app, and each component sits under one of these view contexts. The only way i could see this happening is by preparing everything this way. I just want to type it so to say that this `meta` is possible. If not under a provider it wont be there, if is under a context provider, i know it's shape will be this :(

Comment: To the point of this question it's not clear why `PayloadAction<A,B,C,D>` seems to buried in the internals of RTK. It seems to work only with this `prepare` framework, whereas it seems that it wouldn't hurt if one could just declare their `MyPayloadMetaAction<T=void> = PayloadAction<T,string,MyMeta>`. But then `createSlice` or whatever doesn't return a thing thats compatible with that type.

Comment: The assumption `createSlice` has is that the action that is passed into the case reducer is created by the action creator generated by the same slice. So if there is no `prepare` present, from that point of view, it is impossible that there are any other properties on there. If you want to have the possibility of an extra property on there that is added "outside", I would suggest you write a `getModulePath(action)` function that checks if that meta is there and returns it, maybe with a good fallback.

Comment: I ended up doing that, no fallback actually needed since I want to ignore. I had a chat on redux discord and what I want actually does seem to make sense. RTK docs mention FSA but it seems it’s impossible to implement without using prepare. 
However, actions just need “type” and to be a plain json object. “Payload” is thus just as arbitrary as “meta?”. I think at a minimum they should allow for other types just to be put in and then made partial.

Comment: Although now it clicked when you said “created by the action creator of that slice”. But my understanding was that either it’s not very clear, that prepare is cumbersome (I’d have more actions I need to prepare with the same middleware in my case than not), and that it’s somewhat fuzzy enforcing “payload” but locking others.