# RTK - prepare payload (Typescipt)

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

My understanding is that a 'prepare' notation is needed for purposes of Typescript annotations. I'm struggling to convert this reducer to the 'prepare' annotation. Otherwise, TS throws the following error:

```
TS2339: Property 'meta' does not exist on type '{ payload: any; type: string; }'.
```

The code:

```
 getAllOrders: (state, action) => {
      state.orders = action.payload.orders;

      if (!!action.meta.status && action.meta.status === 'completed') {
        state.allLoaded = true;
      }
    },
```

How would I rewrite it using the 'prepare' format? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked [How to properly use PayloadAction with meta type in redux-toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320668/how-to-properly-use-payloadaction-with-meta-type-in-redux-toolkit) ? It explains how the `prepare` callback is used and how that modifies the `action` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument of `PayloadAction` generic should contain type for `.meta` property.

here's working demo on [Github](https://github.com/rabelais88/stackoverflow-answers/blob/58405e656b1676a9d5690f5f4215b2ddec8af814/75139470-rtk-action-meta/src/app/store.ts#L18-L38)

working code:

```js
// define custom meta
interface CustomMeta {
  status: 'completed' | 'incomplete';
}

// define custom action with meta info
type CustomAction = PayloadAction<number, string, CustomMeta>

export const sampleSlice = createSlice({
  name: "sample",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // Use the PayloadAction type to declare the contents of `action.payload`
    getAllOrders: {
      reducer: (state, action: CustomAction) => {
        // the code below should not get any warnings
        if (action.meta?.status === "completed") {
          // ... do something
        }
      },
      // argument for prepare function has to be manually defined.
      prepare(payload: CustomAction['payload']) {
        return { payload, meta: { status: "completed" } } as CustomAction;
      },
    },
  },
});
```

check the type definition in `createAction.d.ts` for more info:

for shortcut, Cmd+click or Ctrl+click on `PayloadAction` in VSCode

```
export declare type PayloadAction<P = void, T extends string = string, M = never, E = never> = {
    payload: P;
    type: T;
} & ([M] extends [never] ? {} : {
    meta: M;
}) & ([E] extends [never] ? {} : {
    error: E;
});
```